# Switching the file manager in 2sxc to use CK Editor

Tags: 2sxc

I have a DNN 9.0.2 portal with 2sxc 8.5.6. I created a new portal and went to use the file manager in an instance of 2sxc but the file manager comes up blank. The fix for this used to be re-applying folder permissions for the site but in DNN 9.0.2 this no longer seems to work. I suspect there may also be a path issue in DNN 9 as the skin and container folders don't work unless they are in the _default folder.

I found this in the admin logs which also has odd path info of /Portals/1//Portals/0:

AbsoluteURL:/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider/DialogHandler.aspx
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:d4ca78f2-9ea7-4557-a044-8ec005d8faef
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:hNJEY996T+o5kKbcOGn0HQtWNcs=
Message:Unable to complete operation. An unknown error occurred. /Portals/1//Portals/0
StackTrace:
InnerMessage:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
InnerStackTrace:
at DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.TelerikFileBrowserProvider.GetDirectoryItemWithDNNPermissions(String path) at DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.TelerikFileBrowserProvider.ResolveRootDirectoryAsTree(String path)
Source:
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:

Is there a way of getting 2sxc to use the CK Editor file manager instead of the old Rad Editor one?

Comment: So apparently to fix this you just go to bed and the next morning it works fine. It would still be good to know how to switch to using CK Editor for file management in 2sxc though. Can't find any info on how or if it is yet possible.

Comment: If this happens to anyone else try re-syncing your file structure using the admin file manager. It seems that if your file structure gets out of sync you get a blank image manager / document manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the short answer is no - the CK-file manager would also be the "wrong" solution. We're just using the Rad because it's the only one available ATM, but as soon as DNN 9.1 comes out with a real, non-telerik dependend file manager, we'll use that.